# Oracle: how to update "outdated" date in table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

**Our use case**:

For table `USERS`:

update all rows (set value `'N'` for column `ACTIVE`) in case when user was inactive (column `'LAST_VISIT'`) more that `60` minutes.

Google helped me to find how to obtain current time in db (I use `Oracle`):

```
SELECT sysdate FROM dual;
```

Then I found the way how to find the difference in minutes between two dates:

```
SELECT(date1 - date2)*1440
```

Looks like a little bit ugly... but ok.

Now, I am trying to combine all together:

```
UPDATE USERS u 
SET ACTIVE='N' 
WHERE  SELECT((SELECT sysdate FROM dual) - u.LAST_VISIT)*1440 >60;
```

Could you please review my final query.

Is it ok? Or, maybe, it is possible to optimize it?

Comment: You can always run update in transaction, check result and if everything is ok then commit or rollback. Keep in mind you may block other users

Comment: `SYSDATE` is a function, you can reference it directly without a subselect: `WHERE  (sysdate - u.LAST_VISIT)*1440 > 60`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Justin's answer is very good, but it will probably update too many rows.  You should add an extra condition to the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE users u
   SET active = 'N'
    WHERE active <> 'N' AND u.last_visit < sysdate - interval '1' hour;
```

This saves the attempted update for users who are already inactive.  (Note:  this version assumes that `active` does not take the value of `NULL`.)

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify the query

```
UPDATE users u
   SET active = 'N'
 WHERE u.last_visit < sysdate - interval '1' hour;
```

If there is an index on `last_visit` that can be used for the query (because the predicate is sufficiently selective), this query can potentially use that index.